# Monte Carlo sampling ( accept/reject) for geographic dataset

Tags: distributions, python, sampling, monte-carlo, accept-reject

I have a dataset consisting of latitude and longitude and I'm confused on which approach to use to determine the distribution of points so I can apply the monte Carlo accept/reject for sampling. this is the scatter plot of my data with python
[image: scatter plot]

---

Comment: This looks like France land borders plus some noise

Comment: indeed, it is the airspace of the french region....because i'm working on a new sectorization and need the sampling for the genetic algorithm

Comment: @Xi'an I think the one that would mimic the same pattern of my dataset ! No ?

Comment: @Xi'an used the Gaussian one for the first function....... as far as i know the sample rejection needs two distributions.I'm stuck on that part.